# Perform Join in linq

Tags: c#, linq

Perform a join in linQ ?
var a = new List{ 1, 2, 3, 1 };
var duplicated = a.GroupBy(x=> x).Any(b => b.Count > 1);

Comment: Can you show actual C# code for the `struct` types instead of pseudo-code? And, no, you can use LINQ without transforming the data. Also, you depending on which table has millions of rows, you might be better off indexing the data, so are the values in column a and c unique per row? Are columns a and c always first position of the rows?

Comment: Also, what C# type do you expect for the result? Another table `struct`?

Comment: Also, why does `table1` not have the `a` field in your sample? I don't think that code will compile...

Comment: A `class` and a `struct` has some important differences - can you update your question to be accurate?

Comment: If there are duplicate `a` or `c` entries, what do you expect the answer to contain? The cross product of the matches? The first matching `c` for each `a` value? Something else?

Comment: What does "all column from table a and b" mean? What are "table a" and "table b"? Also, your code only extracts a value for `table2` column `d` instead of all columns from `table2` - is that what you want? Maybe it would help if you showed the correct answer...

Comment: What is the third column in your answer? Where did `3,9` come from - it doesn't appear to match your source data??? Where did "3,Fed,2,1" come from??? Where did "3,false,4" come from??? Some column headers would have been nice...

Comment: With your sample code, the result will have two columns labeled "c" - is this expected?

Comment: Is your original data in SQL, or is it in memory? I don't think you should need to materialize all the rows/elements into a List to use LINQ. LINQ operates on IEnumerable and IQueryable which both use deferred execution to avoid the memory hit you are trying to avoid. Intuitively, I think LINQ will be your best bet if you do it right.

Comment: I see no reference to `IReadonlyList<T>` in your sample structures - please fix your question to be correct

Comment: You changed the result to have `null` in the integer columns - do you want `null` now instead of `0`???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I understand you issue. You have a class (call it `table`) that has a property `List<string>` with column labels called `X`, and a `List<List<object>>` property called `Y` that represents the data rows.

```
class table {
    public List<string> X { get; set; } // headers
    public List<List<object>> Y { get; set; } // rows
}
```

You have two `table`s (call them `t1` and `t2`) and you want to left join them on one or more columns and create a new `table` object containing the data from the join. The left hand side will be duplicated for multiple matches on the right hand side. The right hand side for unmatched rows will be a `List<object>` of `null`s. The result will be filtered to only have desired columns on the right hand side.

(My sample `t1` table is like yours, my sample `t2` table adds a new column "f" that is an integer to match up with `t1` column "c".)

Create an empty right hand side for when there is no matching rhs:

```
var emptyT2 = Enumerable.Repeat((object)null, t2.X.Count).ToList();
```

Create an `IEqualityComparer<object>` to compare the join columns:

```
var jec = new IEnumerableSequenceEqualityComparer<object>();
```

Find the column indices of the columns you want to join on:

```
var t1JoinCols = new List<string> { "a", "c" };
var t1JoinIndices = t1JoinCols.Select(c => t1.X.IndexOf(c)).ToList();
var t2JoinCols = new List<string> { "c", "f" };
var t2JoinIndices = t2JoinCols.Select(c => t2.X.IndexOf(c)).ToList();
```

Create a filter for the right hand side columns you want in the output:

```
var t2wanted = new List<string> { "d", "e", "f" };
var t2wantedIndices = t2.X.Select((x, n) => (x, n)).Where(xn =>
```

t2wanted.Contains(xn.x)).Select(xn => xn.n).ToHashSet();

Create an intermediate query to do the left join and pull the matching data (switch to fluent syntax to pass the `IEqualityComparer<object>`):

```
var t3r = t1.Y.GroupJoin(t2.Y,
                         t1r => t1JoinIndices.Select(n1 => t1r[n1]),
                         t2r => t2JoinIndices.Select(n2 => t2r[n2]),
                         (t1r, t2rg) => (t1r,t2rg),
                         jec)
              .SelectMany(t1rt2rg => t1rt2rg.t2rg.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                 .Select(t2r => t1rt2rg.t1r.Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, t2.X.Count)
                                                                                             .Where(n => t2wantedIndices.Contains(n))
                                                                                             .Select(n => t2r?[n]))
                                                                            .ToList()));
```

Convert the intermediate query into a `table` object by building the new headers and the `List<List<object>>` for the rows:

```
var ans = new table {
    X = t1.X.Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, t2.X.Count)
                              .Where(n => t2wantedIndices.Contains(n))
                              .Select(n => t2.X[n]))
            .ToList(),
    Y = t3r.ToList()
};
```

NOTE: the `GroupJoin` operation in the `t3r` query creates a `Lookup` for the second (in this case `t2.Y`) argument which uses hashcode based O(1) lookup, so there is not much efficiency to be gained by not using LINQ. If you are doing millions of rows in each object, you may want to consider re-writing the whole thing in procedural code to gain a few milliseconds per row.

Here is the `IEnumerableSequenceEqualityComparer` definition:

```
public class IEnumerableSequenceEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<T>> {
    public bool Equals(IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y) =>
        Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y) || (x != null && y != null && (x.SequenceEqual(y)));

    public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<T> obj) {
        // Will not throw an OverflowException
        unchecked {
            return obj.Where(e => e != null).Select(e => e.GetHashCode()).Aggregate(17, (a, b) => 23 * a + b);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @user7112196 It should work the same for 1:1. If you want dynamic query conditions, you are talking a more complicated question. How is the query string provided from the user?

Comment: @user7112196 You misunderstood. What C# type and format is the query conditions provided?

Comment: Sorry I still don't get the point. the conditons for the query is just the string represent the column name to be compare. If i still missunderstood, could you give an example what you want to know ?

Comment: Example: Column names to match will be `List<string>`, one for each table, the same indices in both need to match OR Column names will be in a `string` with a colon separating table1 name from table2 name and a comma separating each column pair, etc.

Comment: With the solution you provide, I am able to concat 2 tables in 1 result tables with the left join. What is the solution when I want to show the result of table one and only some column of the result from table 2 ? I will need to modify the select method like" select new { ColumnNameA = t2r[idexOfColumnNameA], ColumnNameB = t2r[indexOfColumnNameB] ....}.ToList() ?

Comment: @user7112196 Create a `List<int>` or (faster) `HashSet<int>` of the indices you want from the the columns you want. Modify the `select` for `t3r` on `t2r` to either be `Concat(t2r.Select((v,n) => (v,n)).Where(vn => wantedIndices.Contains(vn.n)).Select(vn => vn.v))` or `Concat(Enumerable.Range(0,t2.X.Length).Where(n => wantedIndices.Contains(n)).Select(n => t2r[n])`. Do something similar for `t2.X` to create the correct `X`.

Comment: @user7112196 I re-write the answer to match the new conditions. It would really be helpful if you posted the question you actually wanted answered.

Comment: But still I put your answer als correct because it show me the solution for the question i have:) Would be nice if you could check the query and output some result to compare

Comment: @user7112196 I use LINQPad to test and it works fine. Please test with the sample data, adding column "f" or remove it from the join conditions and just match "a" to "c".